# Getting a Vanity URL from FB login API

Tags: php, url, curl, facebook-login, vanity

Our application requires the user to login through Facebook’s API. Facebook throws these parameters:

1. ID
2. First Name, Last Name
3. Email ID
4. APPed URL

Our program was supposed to use the APP URL as input, use CURL functionality of PHP, and get the redirected URL from Facebook.

When redirected Facebook is throwing this login URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fapp_scoped_user_id%2F10210167107598661%2F
```

How can we get the actual vanity URL instead of the login URL?

Comment: what vanity url exactly do you need? there is only one login url. do you mean the redirect url? what do you want to do exactly? can you give an example?

Comment: Basically we need public profile url

Comment: you mean, with the username? what for exactly? you can´t get the username and the real url anymore.